# how to build lightweight continous connection monitoring using ping?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ping, tee

I want to build a connection monitor script using ping that sends off, let's say 10 pings every so often(~once an hour) 24/7 and record the output to a file for later analysis. So far, I've got the following (every 10 seconds for testing):

```
$ watch -n 10 ping -c 10 amazon.com;date +%s|tee -a ping.out
```

it does write to ping.out but it does not seem to be appending to the previous contents even though the `-a` flag is provided, why is this?

I tried out a bit and removed some un wanted contents but I still don't have it appending to the previously recorded output:

```
watch -n 10 `ping -c 10 amazon.com | awk '{print $5 $8}';date +%s` >> ping.out
```

Comment: Check the quoting. From your first command, only the output of `date` will be passed to `tee`, after finishing the `watch` command. In your second command you use backquotes which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
while true; do ( ping -c 10 amazon.com; date +%s ) >> ping.out; sleep 10; done
```

You can break loop by `ctrl + c` or `ctrl + z` next `kill %1`